# How to segue to another storyboard with UIAlertAction handler:

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a modal pop open when a user clicks a button using UIAlertController.

```
let agreeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: .Default, handler: nil)
```

Currently the handler is set to nil, but I would like for it to take the user to a viewcontroller in another storyboard. I tried the following which does not seem to work.

```
handler: UIViewController *theInitialViewController = [secondStoryBoard otherViewController];
```

Any direction or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handler` parameter is a block that takes a `UIAlertAction` and returns `Void`. Your handler parameter should therefore look something like this:

```
{(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: self);
})
```

For future reference: [UIAlertController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html)